# Actual CPU usage per database

Tags: sql-server

I would like to measure the current of the CPU usage for a particular database and I wrote the following query in order to obtain this information. However, I could not be sure about the accuracy of this query.

```
DECLARE @Fm INT;
DECLARE @FTime DATETIME;
SELECT @FTime = getdate(),@Fm = SUM(dmqs.total_worker_time) 
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats dmqs 
CROSS APPLY 
(SELECT 
CONVERT(INT, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(dmqs.plan_handle)
WHERE attribute = N'dbid') dmpa
where DatabaseID=7
GROUP BY dmpa.DatabaseID
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:01'
SELECT CAST((SUM(dmqs.total_worker_time) - @Fm)* 1.0  / SUM(dmqs.total_worker_time)  * 100 AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats dmqs 
 CROSS APPLY 
 (SELECT 
 CONVERT(INT, value) AS [DatabaseID] 
 FROM sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes(dmqs.plan_handle)
 WHERE attribute = N'dbid') dmpa
 where DatabaseID=7
 GROUP BY dmpa.DatabaseID
```

Comment: To be precise, what you have here is the total worker time of queries that involve objects in a particular database. It is not completely meaningful to talk of "CPU usage per database" since queries can span databases, nor does the engine itself partition CPU resources per database. But that brings us to: what's your question?

Comment: Jeroen, you are so right about your approach and I agree with you but I would like to obtain the current CPU consumption of a particular database. sys.dm_exec_query_stats DMV returns the cumulative data about this information

Comment: @JeroenMostert  That's not "queries that involve objects in a particular database", that would be `sys.dm_exec_query_plan.dbid`.  `sys.dm_exec_plan_attributes.dbid` is "plans plans for sessions connected to a particular database", which for the paradigm case of single-database plans run from the target database, is what OP wants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at Glen Berry's diagnostic queries.  He has some CPU related ones including a breakdown of the CPU usage per database in an instance.
https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/glenn/category/dmv-queries/